# Password for in app purchases setup says Apple ID you entered couldn't be font even if its right

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, storekit

When ever i type in my password after the prompt goes up and it ask me for me password even if its correct it says. password can't be fond "Apple ID you entered couldn't be fond of your password was incorrect. and the Remove adds button doesn't do anything

Code:

```
   import Foundation
   import AVFoundation
    import SpriteKit
    import GameKit
   import UIKit
   import StoreKit




         class ThirdScene: SKScene, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {



let RemoveaddsButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayAltenative")
let RestorePurchases = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StopButton")
var iAdLabel = SKLabelNode()






override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        //----------------------------------------------
    iAdLabel.text = "I am An Advertisment"
    iAdLabel.fontSize = 20
    iAdLabel.zPosition = 20
    iAdLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    iAdLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.70)
    self.addChild(iAdLabel)
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.RemoveaddsButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.70, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.20)
    RemoveaddsButton.zPosition = 100
    RemoveaddsButton.size = CGSize(width: 115, height: 170)
    self.addChild(self.RemoveaddsButton)
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    self.RestorePurchases.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.10, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.20)
    RestorePurchases.zPosition = 100
    RestorePurchases.size = CGSize(width: 115, height: 170)
    self.addChild(self.RestorePurchases)







    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "SkateLinesNolliePackage")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")
    }
    }

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func buyProduct() {
        println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            list.append(product as! SKProduct)
        }
    }
    func removeAd() {
        iAdLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height * 9.70)
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")

        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "SkateLinesNolliePackage":
                removeAd()


            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

        }

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored. You may have to restart the app before banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }


    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("add paymnet")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID {
                case "SkateLinesNolliePackage":

                    //Here you should put the function you want to execute when the purchase is complete
                    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "You may have to restart the app before the banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()
                default:
                    println("IAP not setup")
                }

                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                println("default")
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
    }
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        println("remove trans");
    }




override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        name = "RemoveaddsButton"
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.RemoveaddsButton {
            for product in list {
                var prodID = product.productIdentifier
                if(prodID == "SkateLinesNolliePackage") {
                    p = product
                    buyProduct()  //This is one of the functions we added earlier
                    break;


            }
        }
    }

        let location1 = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location1) == self.RestorePurchases {
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        }
    }

   }
    }
```

Comment: Is this app in the app store? If not, are you testing in-app purchses using the test account?

Comment: Also, your ads won't remove because in the .Purchases, .Restored case you don't call any function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a sandbox tester. Go to iTunes Connect, click on my  apps, then click on the app that you made. Next, click prerelease. After that, click on internal testers. After you do that, click on users and roles. Then, click sandbox testers and create a tester with a fake email and password that is not used in any other apple id. The in app purchase should then work with that id.